# How to make table rows height be in sync for emails

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I'm creating email with html template. One of the things is table of 4 boxed with 1 image box and 2 boxed of other content.

When screen resizes, image also gets resized. In this context:

**Is there a possibility to make each of those 2 rows share same height, bearing in mind that row 1 has a dynamic image that shrinks?**

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" style="background-color:green;">
      <p>
        Some content
      </p>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300?text=%20">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"  style="background-color:green;">
      <p>
        Some content
      </p>
    </td>
    <td width="50%"  style="background-color:green;">
      <p>
        Some content
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Link to fiddle with HTML a table - https://jsfiddle.net/dL2zogxr/1/

Comment: If you don't need to put other content into one of the columns of the second row one idea would be to place a second (dummy)image in there that has the same scale as the first image ...

Comment: I'd suggest, since your image is 300px wide you setup a break that the columns break. when you have your image on mobile 160px wide and the text also 160px wide, the image is too small and the text would wrap like crazy. Google "fluid template", if you want to break the table, and create a more responsive email